# Teamcity showAgreement.html has too many redirects

Tags: google-chrome, redirect, teamcity

i just installed Teamcity 7.1.2 on my ubuntu. when i start teamcity, it is configuring some things, and after that it shows the following site:

localhost:8111/showAgreement.html with the following error:

Fehler 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): Zu viele Umleitungen.

im using google chrome, but i tested it with safari and firefox.

Im using Ubuntu 12.04 in a vm fusion virtual environemnt.

does anybody has an idea how can i solve this?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm.. ok i now deleted teamcity from the computer, restarted it again and installed teamcity again and look at that, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For me this happened when Teamcity didn't have write permissions to the directory where it was installed.

Doing "chown teamcity-user:teamcity-user teamcity-top-dir" resolved this for me. No re-install needed.

Answer (score 0):

On docker, run for mounted folders:

```
chown -R 1000:1000 data/ log/
```